# If an asteroid obliterated Planet Earth, could that be interpreted as God's "Second Flood"?

Tags: eschatology, revelation, gospels, flood-of-noah, meaning

I have a hypothetical question, in search of a Biblical-based doctrinal answer.

1. A man and a woman participate in NASA's very first two-way expedition to Mars.
2. After reaching Mars, they look back and they see an asteroid obliterate Planet Earth.

Beyond the immediate practical implications, could the couple possibly view the asteroid's collision with Planet Earth as a "Second Flood", meant to purge the planet of all of its wickedness?

Or has God guaranteed that a "Second Flood" will never happen? And that any such unfortunate event could only be part of the natural order of the universe?

What do the Gospels and the Book of Revelation say about this type of scenario which, while hypothetical, is certainly plausible? Bottom Line: I'm wondering if Scripture tells us that either God reserves the right to "cleanse the Earth" again with a "Second Flood" or that He has explicitly ruled out a "Second Flood" from ever happening again.

**EDIT:** Please root your response in Scripture/Doctrine. Philosophical and sociological answers are off-topic on this site.

**EDIT 2:** To date, three answers have been submitted, all three are rooted in Scripture, and all three seem correct to me. Thanks so much!

Comment: This isn't a great question for this site: it's speculative and based on a hypothetical situation, it doesn't ask of any denomination or other Christian perspective, it doesn't address doctrine, it doesn't address the scriptures.

Comment: @curiousdannii: `...It doesn't address doctrine, it doesn't address the scriptures.` ON THE CONTRARY!!! I'm SPECIFICALLY ASKING FOR A SCRIPTURE-BASED RESPONSE!! `I have a hypothetical question, in search of a Biblical-based doctrinal answer.`

Comment: @curiousdanii: Take a looksie at the three submitted answers. All three are Scripture-based, and all three are... CORRECT!!!

Comment: There's no way to know if they are correct or not. Besides, many Christians think that Revelation does describe an asteroid hitting the earth, so anyone could write an answer saying "yes". The problem isn't with the answers, but with your question. The answers address the scriptures, but your question doesn't really. You need to explain the perspective of any-worldwide-judgement-being-referred-to-as-a-flood more, and preferably from the scriptures. You need to state whether you're asking about judgement at the end of time or not.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, no second obliteration

God said this to Noah

> I will establish my covenant with you, that never again shall all creatures be destroyed by the waters of a flood; there shall not be another flood to devastate the earth.

[Gen 9:11](http://www.usccb.org/bible/gn/9:29)

Sirach says ita not just a flood, because God didn't make that exceptionally specific.

> NOAH, found just and perfect, renewed the race in the time of devastation. Because of his worth there were survivors, and with a sign to him the deluge ended. A lasting covenant was made with him, that never again would all flesh be destroyed

[Sir 44:17-18](http://www.usccb.org/bible/sir/44:17)

He says that all flesh won't be destroyed, but leaves out the cause of all flesh being destroyed.

However, Jesus says in the [luke](http://www.usccb.org/bible/luke/17) that the last days will be like the days of Noah and there'll be fire coming out of the sky like at Sodom, and St. Peter [reiterates Him](http://www.usccb.org/bible/2pt/3:10).  However, Peter [and Paul](http://www.usccb.org/bible/1cor/3:13) both talk about fire being the thing that tests us especially in connection with the last days and judgement.

So, if it's to be a final calamity, the fire that obliterates everything may have a more supernatural origin than some dumb asteroid falling in line with the Earths orbit.

So that's both sides of the argument, I'm not going to try to interpret what it means as you didn't ask for a specific denominations perspective.

Answer (score 0):

In Genesis 9:11-15 it states:

"And I will establish my covenant with you; neither shall all flesh be cut off any more by the waters of a flood; neither shall there any more be a flood to destroy the earth. And God said, This is the token of the covenant which I make between me and you and every living creature that is with you, for perpetual generations: I do set my bow in the cloud, and it shall be for a token of a covenant between me and the earth. And it shall come to pass, when I bring a cloud over the earth, that the bow shall be seen in the cloud: And I will remember my covenant, which is between me and you and every living creature of all flesh; and the waters shall no more become a flood to destroy all flesh."

Then later in Revelation 21:1-7 it says:

"And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea. And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be their God. And God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes; and there shall be no more death, neither sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the former things are passed away. And he that sat upon the throne said, Behold, I make all things new. And he said unto me, Write: for these words are true and faithful. And he said unto me, It is done. I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the end. I will give unto him that is athirst of the fountain of the water of life freely. He that overcometh shall inherit all things; and I will be his God, and he shall be my son."

Here He shows he will never destroy the earth with water again, to destroy all flesh. Then one day, after the Antichrist, false witness, and Satan is phisically defeated, He will make a new heaven and earth, and God will descend and build His city here. And it is here, the "2nd earth" that God will establish us forever. To be called children of God, and for us to say, He is our God.

Answer (score 0):

The story of Noah says God will never flood the world again.

Genesis 8:21-22

> 21 And the Lord smelled a sweet savour; and the Lord said in his heart, I will not again curse the ground any more for man's sake; for the imagination of man's heart is evil from his youth; neither will I again smite any more every thing living, as I have done.
> 22 While the earth remaineth, seedtime and harvest, and cold and heat, and summer and winter, and day and night shall not cease.

And in Genesis 9:11

> And I will establish my covenant with you, neither shall all flesh be cut off any more by the waters of a flood; neither shall there any more be a flood to destroy the earth.

And the 2nd epistle of Peter in the New Testament says this time the world will be destroyed by fire. ([2 Peter 3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%203&version=KJV):2-13)

> 2 Peter 3:6-7  Whereby the world that then was, being overflowed with water, perished: But the heavens and the earth, which are now, by the same word are kept in store, reserved unto fire against the day of judgment and perdition of ungodly men.
>
> 2 Peter 3:10-11  But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night; in the which the heavens shall pass away with a great noise, and the elements shall melt with fervent heat, the earth also and the works that are therein shall be burned up. Seeing then that all these things shall be dissolved, what manner of persons ought ye to be in all holy conversation and godliness,